# Native camera ionic make app crash after taking picture

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have tried some solutions out there but my app keep crahsed (I test it on ios device)

My code

```
getPictureFromCamera() {
    return this.getImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA);
  }

  getPictureFromPhotoLibrary() {
    return this.getImage(this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY);
  }

  getImage(pictureSourceType, quality = 100, allowEdit = true, saveToAlbum = true) {
    const options = {
      quality,
      allowEdit,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      sourceType: pictureSourceType,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: saveToAlbum
    };


    return this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageData => {
      const base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      return base64Image;
    }, error => {
      console.log('CAMERA ERROR -> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
}
```

I also add targetWidth and targetHeight
I use cordova_plugin version 4.0.2

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.2"/>
```

I also add edit-config to ios version like this in config.xml

```
  <platform name="ios">
    <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>need photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
      <string>need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
    </edit-config>
  </platform>
```

But my app still crashes after I take the picture

Comment: [SOLVED]: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2020#issuecomment-337991863